# Trouble downloading csv file laravel (content in response but doesn't download)

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I'm trying to generate and then download a csv file in Laravel 9.
The generation is ok at the correcte location (public/files/OUT/) but i'm getting the content in the response and no download occurs.

here is my code :

```
    $path = storage_path('app\public\files\OUT\\');
    $filename='dataTemplate';

    $f = fopen($path.$filename.'.csv', 'wb');        
    // => PUT DATAS IN CSV => no problem
    fclose($f);
    // file is generated successfully at path location

    $headers = [
        'Content-Type' => 'text/csv',
     ];

    return response()->download($path.'dataTemplate.csv','dataTemplate.csv',$headers);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: app\public\files\OUT\\ is it really 2 backslashes? and are you sure about backslashes?

Comment: @Daniel, that's for escaping the last backslash FYI.

Comment: Are you sure you see the contents and not any error message? I doubt !

Comment: @OMi Shah, Yes sure ! I see my datas and status code 200 as well

Comment: @AdBess, can you try ``application/csv`` or ``application/octet-stream`` as the ``content-type``?

Comment: @OMi Shah, not working, and still getting the datas in response

Comment: what server you're working on? Did you make any changes in the htaccess file?

Comment: @OMi Shah, on localhost for now, no htaccess file.

Comment: @Omi Shah , Any idea ?

Comment: @AdBess, no idea. I don't know how this code is working in the first place, when it should not be working. Can you create a new laravel 9 project and try to output download response without reading/writing to the CSV file.

Comment: @Omi Shah, thanks :  same problem on a fresh laravel 9 project  without data. in csv...